How to handle auto slash(/) with Cypress type()
I'm currently automating testing for an eCommerce website, I'm designing an e2e order placing test flow, at the payment details page i have my visa payment option selected, Cypress has managed to type() the card number (that was no issue) but when I get to the card expiration date date inout field which is MM/YY. When we normally type ourselves the first digit which is MM then this forward slash (/) is automatically added I've had found many good locators for this inout field but when Cypress tries to ty this is then my test fails and the expiration date inout field say's that the date is invalid, here: a snipped ou my code (sorry I cannot share much as this is corporate)
/// cy.get('[class="braintree-credit-card-container"]').find('#braintree-hosted-field-expirationDate').click({force: true}).type('5','2025')///
Can someone help me out with this please I'm just not finding a workaround for this. Thanks!!

I have also tried using this: cy.get('iframe[id="braintree-hosted-field-expirationDate"]').click().type('0525') and the field it still says that the date is invalid.

In a Cypress test <iframe> elements require special handling, because they create an isolated document to sandbox the code from the rest of the page.
The easiest way is with the cypress-iframe package.
yarn add 'cypress-iframe'

Activate the package with an import in cypress/support/e2e.js
import 'cypress-iframe`

In the test, use cy.iframe() instead of cy.get()
cy.iframe('#braintree-hosted-field-expirationDate')
  .find('input')
  .type('0525')

cy.iframe('#braintree-hosted-field-expirationDate')
  .find('input')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', '05 / 25')



Screenshot 2024-04-29 at 19.06.33

SecurityError:
Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.net" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
This is what I get in my Cypress test runner, what is causing this though?

The displaying a credit card form if Braintree in my case, what would be a workaround for this, I would really not want to switch off the the web browsers security.

I would like to keep security in place but also to allow Cypress to be able to access the iframes and avoid that error. Also thanks again taking your time to helping out I just started using Cypress not long ago.
